# useradd prompt user to change password at first login

Tags: linux, users, password, useradd, administration

what option should I add to my useradd command such that when the user logs in for the first time he's prompted to change the password or something?

I was thinking about this, but not sure if it's the right option:

```
useradd -K PASS_MAX_DAYS=0 username
```

Answer (score 2):

I use the passwd command to expire a password after setting it.

passwd -e

Answer (score 2):

The command

```
chage -d 0 user01
```

forces the `user01` to update its password on the next login.